# Python "TypeError: 'empleado' object is not callable"

Tags: python

tengo un problema con este error. Observen el siguiente código:

```
class persona():
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad, residencia):
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.edad=edad
        self.residencia=residencia
    def descripcion(self):
        print("Nombre:", self.nombre, "Edad:", self.edad, "Residencia:", self.residencia)

class empleado(persona):
    def __init__(self, sueldo, antiguedad, nombre_empleado, edad_empleado, residencia_empleado):
        super().__init__(nombre_empleado, edad_empleado, residencia_empleado)

        self.sueldo=sueldo
        self.antiguedad=antiguedad
    def descripcion(self):
        super().descripcion()
        print("Sueldo empleado:", self.sueldo, "Antiguedad empleado:", self.antiguedad)


persona=empleado(23000, "13 años", "Juan", 34, "Berlín, Alemania.")
persona.descripcion()
persona2=persona("María", 23, "Salvador")
persona2.descripcion()
```

El error es el siguiente:

```
Nombre: Juan Edad: 34 Residencia: Berlín, Alemania.
Sueldo empleado: 23000 Antiguedad empleado: 13 años
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pruebas.py", line 22, in <module>
    persona2=persona("María", 23, "Salvador")
TypeError: 'empleado' object is not callable

***Repl Closed***
```

Si coloco esto:

```
persona2=persona("María", 23, "Salvador")
persona2.descripcion()
```

Arriba de la creación de la instancia de la clase empleado, no ocurre nada, pero cuando lo coloco debajo, me indica eso. La verdad no tengo la menor idea de cual es el problema, ¿Alguien podría explicarme a fondo? Muchísimas gracias.

*No importa si le cambió de nombre a los métodos, al principio pensé tener igual nombre los métodos de ambas clases podían ocasionar el problema, pero no es el caso. Si llamo a persona2 luego de llamar a una instancia de clase empleado ocurre el error*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloca un `print(type(persona))` antes y después de esta instrucción:

```
print(type(persona))
persona=empleado(23000, "13 años", "Juan", 34, "Berlín, Alemania.")
print(type(persona))
```

El resultado será

```
<class 'type'>
<class '__main__.empleado'>
```

Lo que pasa es que estas reemplazando la clase `persona` con un objeto de la clase `empleado`. La clase deja de existir, y por tanto, ya no puedes crear objetos.

Solución:

Usar nombres distintos para clases y objetos. Seguir la convención de nombrar las clases con mayúscula inicial.